# Disable reloading of rows when Up scrolling in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to disable reusing of cells when scrolled **upwards**.  When scrolling downwards it should be loaded as reusable cell and kept in memory.

This is to increase the user experience of my application.

Comment: Why of you want to do that? I guess it's impossible. Anyway, all information in loaded cells will be available for user.

Comment: @Sranjith You can edit your question, and express more detail, I can not understand.

Comment: I dont think it is possible. Reusable cell will be used whenever a cell which isn't in the view comes into view. Maybe you could explain your use case in more detail so that the community can suggest you approaches.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. You should be asking why your user's experience is suffering when they scroll a table view upwards.